# Error : Nest cannot export component / module that is not a part of the currently processed module (DatabaseModule)

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, nestjs

I'm programming a really simple app allowed make CRUD feature on a PostgreSQL DB using express.
When I run my program I get this error : 
Error: Nest cannot export component / module that is not a part of the currently proccessed module (DatabaseModule). Please verify whether each exported unit is available in this particular context.

I really don't understand why... In the app.module.ts, I import DatabaseModule, which calls database provider (where is my postreSQL connection).

I'm new on typescript, and I'm lost : / 
I only post the entry point of app, but I can send more if it's not enough and thank's for the help :

```
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import { ApplicationModule } from './src/app.module';
import * as express from 'express';
import 'ts-node/register';

async function bootstrap() {
    let instance: any;
    instance = express();
    const app = NestFactory.create(ApplicationModule, instance);
    app.then(instance => instance.listen(3000), () => console.log('Application is listening on port 3000'));
}

bootstrap();
```

This app.module.ts

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { MainController } from './controller/main.controller';

import { CatsModule } from './cats.module';
import { CatsController } from './controller/cats.controller';

import { OwnerModule } from './owner.module';
import { OwnerController } from './controller/owner.controller';

import {CatfoodController} from './controller/catfood.controller';
import { CatfoodModule } from './catfood.module';

import { DatabaseModule } from './database/database.module';

@Module({
  controllers: [
      MainController,
      CatsController,
      CatfoodController,
      OwnerController,
  ],
    modules: [
        DatabaseModule,
        CatsModule,
        CatfoodModule,
        OwnerModule,
    ],
})

export class ApplicationModule {}
```

And database.module :

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { databaseProviders } from './database.providers';

@Module({
    components: [...databaseProviders],
    exports: [...databaseProviders],
})
export class DatabaseModule {}
```

Github : https://github.com/lukile/catProject

Comment: Show DatabaseModule, AppModule

Comment: I updated the post

Comment: @shai - please mark the answer as the accepted answer if you are happy with it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

I think you need to put the `modules` in `imports` array, not `modules` array. Please double check. And do `CatsModule` and `CatfoodModule` have their corresponding `controllers` in their class (which they should)? You don't have to put every controllers in `ApplicationModule`.

Comment: Yes you were right, 
I modified the code to only imports modules,in array and I changed to add TypeOrmModule.forRoot() instead of DatabaseModule() (even if I think it wouldn't change a thing).
Now there's another error :
 Nest can't resolve dependencies of the CatsService (?). Please verify whether [0] argument is available in the current context..
I export my catsService in catsModule and my catsService constructor looks like to : 
constructor(@InjectRepository(Cat) private readonly catRepository: Repository<Cat>)

Comment: Do you have `TypeOrm.forFeature` in CatsModule?

Comment: @Module({
    imports: [TypeOrmModule.forFeature([Cat])],
    components: [CatsService],
    controllers: [CatsController],
})
I do : /
I updated to share github

Comment: I finally solved my problem. I restarted from the beginning, and I finally can create, read, update and delete from postgreSQL database with API connection.
If it could help anyone my github is up to date :)
Thank's for your help

Comment: @Shaï good to hear. You mind posting your own answer and state clearly what was the problem and how you solved it?

Comment: Yes sorry ^^. The problem was I was lost : I had 2 modules and I didn't see it... And obviously I called the bad one, where I didn't import TypeOrmModule.forFeature().
In my service I used '@Inject' instead '@InjectRepository'. It couldn't work : /

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you created a module, but you didn't configure them. When you create a module using a `@Module`, you need to create at least an empty controllers array inside the `@Module`.

```js
import { Module } from "@nestjs/common";

@Module({
  controllers: []
})
export class AppModule {

}
```